# Изменение фона блоков при наведении на один из них

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Помогите мне сделать эффект. У меня есть блоки с категориями. При наведении на один из блоков, нужно, что бы у всех остальных остальных блоков, включая на который навели, изменялся фон.

Вот пример, как нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник: http://www.veintidosgrados.com/work

И можно ли это как-то сделать только с одним `CSS` ?

Comment: Да можно. А плавную анимацию вам обеспечит transition. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: А можно подробнее?) transition не очень интересует.. а вот как менять background на всех элементах когда используешь hover.. было бы интересно взглянуть)

Comment: Хм, ну есть вариантик, но в реализации сложненько

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Одним `CSS` вряд ли. Но предлагаю такое гибкое решение. Вы можете добавлять сколько угодно пунктов, но картинка будет нормально отображаться:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wallpaper__item');

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
   var bg_n = this.getAttribute('class').replace(/^.*wallpaper\_{2}item\_bg\-{2}(\d+).*$/, '$1');
   document.querySelector('.wallpaper').classList.add('wallpaper_bg--'+bg_n);
    
    var bg_i = document.createElement('div');
    bg_i.setAttribute('class', 'wallpaper__item-bg wallpaper__item-bg_img--'+bg_n);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
     (function(i) {
      var item__bg = bg_i.cloneNode(true);
       item__bg.style.backgroundSize = (100 * items.length) + '% 100%';
      item__bg.style.backgroundPositionX = '-' + (100 * i) + '%';
      items[i].appendChild(item__bg);
        item__bg.classList.add('wallpaper__item-bg_show');
        
       setTimeout(function() {
        item__bg.classList.remove('wallpaper__item-bg_show');
       }, 500);
      })(i);
    };
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
   var bg_n = this.getAttribute('class').replace(/^.*wallpaper\_{2}item\_bg\-{2}(\d+).*$/, '$1');
   document.querySelector('.wallpaper').classList.remove('wallpaper_bg--'+bg_n);
    
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      var items__bg = item.querySelectorAll('.wallpaper__item-bg');
      for(var i = 0; i < items__bg.length; i++){
       (function(i) {
        items__bg[i].classList.add('wallpaper__item-bg_hide');
         setTimeout(function() {
           if(items__bg.length > 0 && items__bg[i].parentNode){
           item.removeChild(items__bg[i]);
            };
        }, 500);
       })(i);
      };
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wallpaper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.wallpaper__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wallpaper__item-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Появление/исчезновение */
.wallpaper__item-bg.wallpaper__item-bg_show {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 0.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes show {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}  
}
.wallpaper__item-bg.wallpaper__item-bg_hide {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: hide 0.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes hide {
  from {opacity: 1}
  to {opacity: 0}  
}

/* Анимация качания */
.wallpaper__item:nth-child(2n+2) {
  animation: size__type0 10s infinite;
}
.wallpaper__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
  animation: size__type1 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes size__type0 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  to { 
    transform: scale(1);
  }  
}
@keyframes size__type1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to { 
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }  
}

.wallpaper__item-bg_img--0 {background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg')}
.wallpaper__item-bg_img--1 {background-image: url('http://www.anawalls.com/repic/image.php?src=http://www.anawalls.com/images/nature/sea-surface-calm-smooth-surface-light-night.jpg&h=540&w=960')}
.wallpaper__item-bg_img--2 {background-image: url('http://www.ellf.ru/uploads/posts/2015-07/1437948968_001-ellf.ru.jpg')}
.wallpaper__item-bg_img--3 {background-image: url('http://www.sunhome.ru/i/wallpapers/134/oboi-na-rabochii-stol-gorod.orig.jpg')}
.wallpaper__item-bg_img--4 {background-image: url('http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg')}
```

```html
<div class="wallpaper">
  <div class="wallpaper__item wallpaper__item_bg--0"></div>
  <div class="wallpaper__item wallpaper__item_bg--1"></div>
  <div class="wallpaper__item wallpaper__item_bg--2"></div>
  <div class="wallpaper__item wallpaper__item_bg--3"></div>
  <div class="wallpaper__item wallpaper__item_bg--4"></div>
</div>
```

Пример на стороннем редакторе: [jsfiddle.net-sct48ty9](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/sct48ty9/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Просто волшебно)))

Answer (score 0):

Я придумал, как можно реализовать данную задачу на одном CSS. У данного решения есть свои плюсы.

Плюсы:

1. Меньшее употребление ресурсов при быстрой смене картинок
2. Более плавная анимация
3. Это помпезно круто :)

Минусы:

1. Большое количество кода
2. Сложность реализации
3. Сложные вычисления размеров
4. Нету гибкости (для новых блоков нужно переделывать вычисления, а это
   *пункт 3*)
5. Все пункты и вычисления нужно указывать в ручную

Пример:

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav__item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 102px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav__item-bg {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 102px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav__item-img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% + 70px);
    height: 100%;
    background-size: calc(400% - (35px * 4)) 100%;
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(1) .nav__item-img {
  background-position: 0%;
}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(2) .nav__item-img {
  background-position: calc(-100% + 35px);
}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(3) .nav__item-img {
  background-position: calc(-200% + 90px);
}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(4) .nav__item-img {
  background-position: calc(-300% + 135px);
}

.nav__item-img:nth-child(1) {background-image: url(http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/4/6/8/8310864.jpg)}
.nav__item-img:nth-child(2) {background-image: url(http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/6/93/550/93550371_MiosgKjpRqE.jpg)}
.nav__item-img:nth-child(3) {background-image: url(http://bm.img.com.ua/nxs/img/prikol/images/large/9/3/309339_889006.jpg)}
.nav__item-img:nth-child(4) {background-image: url(http://www.zooclub.ru/skat/img.php?w=700&h=700&img=./attach/7328.jpg)}

.nav__item-bg:nth-child(1) .nav__item-img:nth-child(1) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(2) .nav__item-img:nth-child(2) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(3) .nav__item-img:nth-child(3) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(4) .nav__item-img:nth-child(4) {opacity: 1}

.nav__item:hover ~ .nav__list > .nav__item-bg .nav__item-img {opacity: 0}
.nav__item:nth-child(1):hover ~ .nav__list > .nav__item-bg .nav__item-img:nth-child(1) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item:nth-child(2):hover ~ .nav__list > .nav__item-bg .nav__item-img:nth-child(2) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item:nth-child(3):hover ~ .nav__list > .nav__item-bg .nav__item-img:nth-child(3) {opacity: 1}
.nav__item:nth-child(4):hover ~ .nav__list > .nav__item-bg .nav__item-img:nth-child(4) {opacity: 1}

/* Анимации */
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(2n+2), .nav__item:nth-child(2n+2) {
  animation: size__type0 10s infinite;
}
.nav__item-bg:nth-child(2n+1), .nav__item:nth-child(2n+1){
  animation: size__type1 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes size__type0 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.95) skewX(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1) skewX(-10deg);
  }
  to { 
    transform: scale(0.95) skewX(-10deg);
  }  
}
@keyframes size__type1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1) skewX(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.95) skewX(-10deg);
  }
  to { 
    transform: scale(1) skewX(-10deg);
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <!--<Пункты>-->
  <a href="#" class="nav__item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__item"></a>
  <!--<Фоны пунктов>-->
  <div class="nav__list">
    <div class="nav__item-bg">
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__item-bg">
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__item-bg">
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__item-bg">
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
      <div class="nav__item-img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В этом примере я сделал наклонность, как у автора вопроса в примере. Есть ещё версия с сохранением пропорции фона.

Версия №1 (без сохранения пропорции фона): [jsfiddle-1hpps872](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/1hpps872/)
Версия №2 (с сохранением пропорции фона): [jsfiddle-1hpps872-1](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/1hpps872/1/)
Версия №3 (без наклона): [jsfiddle-1hpps872-2](https://jsfiddle.net/1hpps872/2/)

Comment: картинки показываются только на второй и последней плашке. без наведения плашки черные, а должны показывать соответствующие части картинок

Comment: @Grundy, заметил ошибку. Будет возможность - исправлю

Comment: calc вроде не работает на в яблочных системах. Да и делать на технологии в которой отсутствуют маски, как в данном случаи css, это просто извращение.

Comment: @OlmerDale, по этому лучше воспользоваться вариантом со скриптом. А у вас все картинки отображаются?

Comment: Нет, не все. И если быть точным, то Ваша реализация хоть и крутая, но не идентична оригиналу. В оригинале картинка не масштабируется.

Comment: @OlmerDale, я не хочу, что бы пользователи брали и копипастили. Пусть думают головой и дорабатывают под себя :) Не отображается первая и четвёртая?

Comment: все и последняя чаще других.

Comment: @OlmerDale, а сейчас?